# Why is $x^{1.36^x}$ such a good approximate to $\int_{0}^{x}t^t dt$?

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, approximation, tetration

So, once again I was experimenting on Desmos and found that $\int_{0}^{x}t^t dt$ can be approximated pretty well by the function $x^{1.36^x}$.

[image]

It roughly becomes more accurate as $x$ approaches to infinity, but I wonder whether there is an exact of that number in the top e.g.

> What number $n$ makes the approximation of the $\int_{0}^xt^tdt$ by the function $x^{n^x}$ almost perfect as $x$ approaches infinity?

Or a better way of phrasing is:

> What choice of $n$ makes the ratio between $x^{n^x}$ and $\int_{0}^xt^tdt$ approach $1$ as $x$ approaches infinity?

I would like an answer as to why the approximate is such a good one and why it incorporates $x$ to the power of an exponential function.

Comment: I assume by $\int x^x$ you mean $\int_0^x t^tdt$? Also, $\lim_{x\to\infty} x^{n^x}$ is clearly $\infty$, so what exactly do you mean by $\lim_{x\to\infty} x^{n^x}= \int_{}x^x$?

Comment: Yes, your assumption is correct. And I hope I cleared up the rest - Look back at the OP to see the change I made. Sorry if my mathematical terminology is a bit crude

Comment: $\int_{}x^xdx$ is an indefinite integral. It is not the same as $\int_0^x t^tdt$.

Comment: Yep, I see what you mean. Sorry about that.

Comment: What evidence do you have that your approximation is "almost perfect"? I must say, it seems very unlikely to me.

Comment: I never said my approximation was "almost perfect" - I am asking what choice of n I would have to choose in the function $x^{n^x}$ such that its almost perfect - and perfect as x approaches infinity in both functions

Comment: Maybe a good conjecture is the ratio goes to 1?

Comment: Yeah, I should have that earlier... it's exactly what I mean. Thanks

Comment: You could probably use $\dfrac{x^x}{1+\ln x}$ as an approximation for $\int_0^x t^t\,dt$. It's not in the form you were experimenting with, but it should be pretty easy to show that it is a good approximation asymptotically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WEll, $1.36^2$ is close to 2, and $1.36^3$ is close to 3, and $1.36^4$ is close to 4. Thus in general $1.36^x$ isn't that far away from $x$ for $x$ in $[1,5]$ Furthermore, $1.36^x < x$ for some values of $x$ in $[1,5]$ and $1.36^x > x$ for other such $x$. Thus letting $y(x)= 1.36^x$, one would expect that $\int_{1}^a f(x,y(x))dx$ and $\int_1^a f(x,x)dx$ for a continuous function $f$ that is increasing in both variables s.t. $f(u,v)=u^v$.

In fact, it is not that hard to check that say $\frac{2^2}{2^{1.36^2}} = 2^{2-1.36^2}$ which satisfies $1<2^{2-1.36^2} < 1.1$.

Now for large $x$ though, note that $1.36^x >> x$, thus $\int_0^a x^{1.36^x} dx >> \int_0^a x^x$ for say $a > 20$.

Comment: Thanks. I guess that makes sense. However, instead of 1.36, could you use some function of x to approximate it even better?

Comment: @JakubSkop if you did an expansion of $x^x$ then integrated, using $\lim_{x\to 0}x^x=1$ then you would get the exact function. From this just take a few terms and that would form a good approximation

Comment: Well as mentioned in my answer, using an exponential function to approximate breaks down for large $x$, and quite dramatically too; $1.36^x$ for $x=100$ is at least a 30-digit number.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on my comment:
$$e^z=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{z^n}{n!}$$
so for $z=x\ln(x)$ we get:
$$x^x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\left[x\ln(x)\right]^n}{n!}=1+x\ln(x)+\frac{x^2}2\ln^2(x)+...$$
Now integrate termwise